# Align cell contents horizontally in an entire row in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Basically, wanting to select a row and center align the contents of each cell, but can't seem to get it working. Doesn't do anything:

```
For r = 1 To rCount
    wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(c).Cell(r, 1).Select
    textVal = wd.Selection.Text
    If textVal Like "Job*" Then
        wd.Selection.Font.Allcaps = True
        wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(c).Rows(r).Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    End If
Next
```

The `wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(c).Rows(r).Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter` just seems to talk about the row itself being aligned on a page and not the contents. I can find documentation on just a single cell, but not an entire row.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the paragraph format, not the table alignment:

```
With wd.ActiveDocument.Tables(c)
  For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
    With .Cell(r, 1)
      If InStr(.Range.Text, "Job") = 1 Then
        .Range.Font.AllCaps = True
        .Row.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
```

Note, too, that nothing needs to be selected.